# Regex Tags Ignore all td tags inside of tr tag

Tags: html, regex, tags

Is there a possible solution to this problem?

I want a regular expression that ignores all the td tags in the tr tags.
The tr tags are that I'm looking for are incorrect as the ending tag is missing the
"/". So far I have:

```
<tr[^>]*><td(?:(?!</td>).)*</td><tr[^>]*>

<tr[^>]*> This needs to be the beginning of the expression ****

<td(?:(?!</td>).)*</td> This will find everything between <td> and </td>

<tr[^>]*> This needs to be the end of the expression ****
```

This regex doesn't work of course. Here is a sample of text to run the regular expression on:

Sample 1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <title>                  
   </title>
</head>                             
<body>
   <table asdf>
      <tr asdf>
         <td asdf>
            <table asdf>
                <tr asdf: asdf>
                   <td>
                       blah blah blah
                   </td>
               </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td>
              Keep going
          </td>
      <tr> If highlighted to here from first tr tag than correct regex was used
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Sample 2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <title>                  
   </title>
</head>                             
<body>
   <table asdf>
      <tr asdf>
         <td asdf>
            <table asdf>
                <tr asdf: asdf>
                   <td>
                       blah blah blah
                   </td>
               </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td>
              <table asdf>
                <tr asdf: asdf>
                   <td>
                       blah blah blah
                   </td>
               </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
      <tr> If highlighted to here from first tr tag than correct regex was used
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Sample 3:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <title>                  
   </title>
</head>                             
<body>
   <table asdf>
      <tr asdf>
         <td asdf>
            <table asdf>
                <tr asdf: asdf>
                   <td>
                       blah blah blah
                   </td>
               </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td>
              <table>
                <tr>
                   <td>
                       blah blah blah
                   </td>
               </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
      <tr> If highlighted to here from first tr tag than correct regex was used
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Sample 4:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <title>                  
   </title>
</head>                             
<body>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<table class="afdadsf">
    <td></td>
</table>
<br/>
<br/>
<table class="fdafdas">
    <tr><td></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

My desired output is when the regex is executed, the first tr tag till the last tr tag is highlighted using both sample texts above. Assume other sample texts where td tag can contain possibly any value.

Comment: You want to ignore all `<td>` tags in `<tr>`, but isn't the lack of `</tr>` the problem? You should probably include your desired output.

Comment: I don't think a lack of </tr> is the issue. I need to have <tr[^>]*> at the end and beginning of the regex expression since I'm looking for <tr> tags that incorrectly end with <tr>. My desired output is explained in the code section of the sample text. I'll edit my comment and move it outside the code section as well.

Answer (score 0):

based on what was posted and requested, if your Regex engine supports recursion `(?R)` use this pattern:

```
<tr[^>]*>.*(<(\S+)[^>]*>([^<]|(?1))*?<\/\2>).*?<tr[^>]*>
```

may need some extensive testing
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/45)

---

based on the comment below `<tr>` tags are always the outer most, use this pattern `s` option enabled:

```
(<tr[^>]*>.*<tr>)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/102)

Comment: what do you mean by skip over, would you update your question and post expected output. in this updated example match #1 is what you asked to highlight http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/95

Comment: I edited my question and here are my concerns with your answer: 1. I've used this regular expression in all my files and if the expression isn't there then it highlights everything in the file. I have thousands of files to go over. 2. Your regular expression only works for that one sample text.

Comment: Question, is there a chance that after the last "wrong" `<tr>` you would have more `<tr>..</tr>` tags? in other words, is the incorrect tag always the outer most one?

Comment: @developer234, updated my answer above per last comment.

Comment: The regular expression works for sample 3, which demonstrates your regular expression works for everything between the outer tags, which is great. I still found a small problem with the regex according to sample 4 though. Sample 4 should not be highlighted

Comment: example 4 has unbalanced tags, what is the last `<tr>` doing?

Comment: now there are more than one outer most `<tr>` tags per #4.

Comment: Yes, there are 2 outer <tr>,</tr> tags in sample 4. Assume there are many outer <tr> tags in each file.